# Scrape Hidden Number "Click here to show number"

Tags: javascript, php, json, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch number (using PHP scraper) on this [link](http://www.asani.com.pk/lahore/gulberg-town/computers/lenovo-core-i3-3rd-genration-250541#showphone250541)  which is hidden under "show phone number". But I haven't been able to figure out how to do so. I have got other information but I am having trouble figuring this out. I would highly appreciate if someone could kindly guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see where the issue might be?

Comment: FYI: its an image not an actual text

Comment: I think the idea behind hiding the number is so that you cannot scrape it. Do you have any good reasons we should help you to crack their protection? Moreso, if they did their job right, it should be very difficult.

Comment: Yes I don't mind getting the image. The image is generated after fetching it from json file. But not able to figure out how exactly. http://js.asani.com.pk/js/view-app.min.js?1466235 << in this file he sends a ajax request to get_full_phone.json dataType:"json"

Comment: @winhowes could you kindly elaborate on that

Comment: My mistake, I mistyped something when I was testing, you can only get the image

Comment: I don't mind even getting the image.